# How best to do async batched work in node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Imagine I have a node.js program that has to get 100 rows of data from a server at a time, I want to process each row individually that is returned and when say only 10 rows are remaining to be processed I want to download the next 100 rows.

If I used the async module in node.js, what is the 'correct' approach to do this.  Is a cargo, queue or something else considered best practice and how best to trigger when to start loading more rows?

Comment: What do you mean by "rows of data"? Are you piping a stream?

Comment: It's loading rows from a database into a json array.  E.g. loading 100 mysql rows from a table.